# bloqueio de acesso simultâneo - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Preciso bloquear acessos simultaneos com o mesmo login no meu sistema, atualmente utilizo CodeIgniter como framework.

Ao logar no sistema, eu consigo setar 'logado' no BD e no logout é liberado o acesso para aquele usuário.

Problemas: Ao fechar o navegador ou expirar a sessão, não é realizada a rotina de liberação.

Answer (score -1):

Eu já tive esse problema e achei algumas dicas, mas sem efeito, como o `Jquery $(window).unload(function()`, mas nenhuma surtiu efeito.

O melhor que vi que da pra fazer, é:

1- você gravar no banco de dados a data e horário que o usuário logou a cada login;

2- criar uma função que em toda página visitada fique atualizando a cada x minutos, esse horário de login; (pode chamar essa função no `__construct` de cada controller)

3- criar um **evento** no seu banco de dados, que rode um select a cada "y" minutos verificando se a data gravada no banco é menor que 5 minutos por exemplo, de acordo com o tempo que você setou para durar a sessão dele. 
(**observação** se for um site com muitos acessos simultâneos, provavelmente não será uma boa idéia, talvez precise ser um servidor dedicado, pois o evento do banco fica rodando em loop infinito, para que funcione)

Porque se o usuário fechar a página sem querer e quiser voltar onde estava, vai conseguir sem precisar fazer login novamente, devido a sessão ativa.
E se acontecer dele realmente fechar a página sem fazer logoff então você define para 1 minuto após o tempo da sessão expirar, ser o tempo máximo da diferença do horário atual do servidor, com o que está no banco de dados.

Exemplo, sessão setada para 10 minutos, vc configura o tempo para verificar no select entre 11 ou 12 minutos.

Espero ter ajudado. Boa sorte.